# How to label columns in an array ?How to split an array?(Python, numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, label

How would I label the columns in this array. I want to label the left column input and the right column output.

I would also like to split the columns into separate arrays if that is possible ?

```
                     ([[[ 100000.,     233.],
                        [ 100010.,     299.],
                        [ 100020.,     253.],

                        [ 199980.,     243.],
                        [ 200000.,     247.]],

                       [[ 100000.,     295.],
                        [ 100010.,     294.],
                        [ 100020.,     317.],

                        [ 199980.,     307.],
                        [ 199990.,     321.],
                        [ 200000.,     308.]],

                       [[ 100000.,     338.],
                        [ 100010.,     362.],
                        [ 100020.,     337.],

                        [ 199980.,     334.],
                        [ 199990.,     317.],
                        [ 200000.,     326.]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`array[0,:,0]` gives you the "input" column, `array[0,:,1]` the "output". (see [numpy slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)). As for labelling the columns, that is usually where you should consider using a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Convert the array to structured array using [`numpy.core.records.fromarrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> a = np.array(
...   [[[ 100000.,     233.],
...     [ 100010.,     299.],
...     [ 100020.,     253.],
...     [ 199980.,     243.],
...     [ 200000.,     247.]],
...    [[ 100000.,     295.],
...     [ 100010.,     294.],
...     [ 100020.,     317.],
...     [ 199990.,     321.],
...     [ 200000.,     308.]],
...    [[ 100000.,     338.],
...     [ 100010.,     362.],
...     [ 100020.,     337.],
...     [ 199990.,     317.],
...     [ 200000.,     326.]]]
... )
>>> b = np.core.records.fromarrays(
...     a.reshape(-1, 2).T, names='input,output'
... ).reshape(a.shape[:-1])
>>> b[0][0]['input']
100000.0
>>> b[0][0]['output']
233.0
```

### 2. Using slicing:

```
>>> a[..., 0]
array([[ 100000.,  100010.,  100020.,  199980.,  200000.],
       [ 100000.,  100010.,  100020.,  199990.,  200000.],
       [ 100000.,  100010.,  100020.,  199990.,  200000.]])
>>> a[..., 1]
array([[ 233.,  299.,  253.,  243.,  247.],
       [ 295.,  294.,  317.,  321.,  308.],
       [ 338.,  362.,  337.,  317.,  326.]])
```